# how to put view behind navigation bar in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a video view and i am hiding the navigation bar when video starts playing, but the view is stretched to the empty part created after the hiding the navigation bar. I want to play the video in full screen behind the navigation bar. So that when i do hide/show navigation bar the stretching and shrinking of video view should be avoided. Any suggestions are appreciated ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is it basicallly your navigation bar is it a Preloader,..?

for preloader
you can dismiss it like

```
pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: Navigation bar is the system soft key bar (Back, home ...) buttons on ics devices

Answer (score 0):

use full screen window with flag SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION :

```
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION